# CSS z-index full screen in Photogallery

Tags: css, html

I am using html5gallery plugin located here:
http://html5box.com/html5gallery/index.php

The photo gallery is working fine until I click on an image to go fullscreen in Chrome I just get a black screen?

You will notice in the CSS I set the z-index to 999 to no avail.  Any ideas?

http://tinyurl.com/btwwgfm

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was called jQuery more than once in the script.  I removed the second call to jQuery and it worked great.